# Method next() on ReplaySubject not working in subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing, subscribe, replaysubject

I have a that code:

```
enum URLs {
  'STORY_BUILDER' = 'story-builder',
  'IB_VIEW' = 'ib-view',
}

defaultGroupStoryRequest$ = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
defaultGroupIbViewRequest$ = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();



const invalidRequest = R.pathOr(
  false,
  ['extras', 'state', 'invalidRequest'],
  navigation,
);

if (invalidRequest) {
  this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      pairwise(),
    )
    .subscribe((e) => {
      const parts = (e[0] as NavigationEnd).url.split('/');
      const previousPage = parts[parts.length - 1];
      this.defaultGroupIbViewRequest$.next(previousPage === URLs.IB_VIEW);
      this.defaultGroupStoryRequest$.next(previousPage === URLs.STORY_BUILDER);
    });
}
```

And in template:

```
<shared-overlay [isVisible]="defaultGroupStoryRequest$ | async">
<ng-template>
<shared-confirm
  type="warning"
  question="Generating Story for the default group is not allowed."
  label="Please select different group."
  acceptText="Ok"
  acceptButtonStyle="btn-danger-outline"
  [showDeclineButton]="false"
  (accept)="defaultGroupStoryRequest$.next(false)"
>
</shared-confirm>
```

Subscribe is executing but i can't send value using `next()` method to show popup. Why my `next()` method don't execute? I want get previous page, and compare with value from enum, and after display popup on the screen.

Comment: Have you verified `previousPage` is the correct value you want to compare against? I suspect your comparisons are always returning `false`, which would mean your modal would never show.

Comment: After investigation: yes, of course, I do console.log before a next() method and previousPage have a value from the enum. Condition is good. This is interesting because when I put next() method outside subscribe it is working, but when I put this inside subscribe next() working too, I subscribe this stream and value is on the stream, but in html template popup is not visible.

Comment: So, in the template, if you do: `[isVisible]="true"` does it work?  If not, at least you know your where your problem is :-)

Comment: I have changeDetectionStrategy.onPush

Comment: I'm suggesting to place static value as a test to see if modal displays when you know the value is 'true'.  I don't think it should matter if you use onPush strategy or not.

Comment: It seems like maybe the problem is not the replay subject inside subscribe, but rather the template / css or something on that side.